# Menu scrolls for no reason

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a menu that looks this:
[image]

But when I press the up-key to select "Exit" it scrolls everything out of view, like this:
[image]

Other menus don't do this - even in the same strip. It *appears* to be because I've got items that have `Visible=false` **and** are not at the bottom of the menu (I have a Print menu item that isn't always visible).

Obvious work-arounds are: just grey it out instead; actually remove and then add it back in when I want it.

The question is: can I fix it properly without hacking around??!

Comment: Greying out the item might well be preferable from a user experience perspective. It tells the user that 'printing is possible, just not in the current state'. It also preserves the 'shape' of the menu, so the user's eye will always fall in the expected place when looking for other entries.

Comment: I agree - I should perhaps have used a better example. I have other menu items, though, where there is a real need for this. Perhaps I'll just move them to the bottom and hope that works around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to a known bug, see Microsoft Connect issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357453/visibility-change-causes-menu-items-to-scroll).

The workaround suggested is to add a `ToolStripSeperator` as the last item in the menu. This apparently resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as it happens I already disable them too ... (i.e) no effect :(

Comment: @noelicus: See updated answer above, I think it's likely this is your problem.